# How do I iterate on these lists at the same time?

Tags: java, arrays, list

This is what I want to achieve:

```
    public ArrayList<Point> startPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
    public ArrayList<Point> endPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();

            for (Point startPoint : startPoints) { // <-- How do I do I do 2 at the same time?
                 g.fillOval(startPoint .x, startPoint.y, 10, 10);
                 g.drawLine(startPoint .x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
            }
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985266/how-to-iterate-through-two-arraylists-simultaneously

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a "normal" `for` with an index `i`.

```
// if list1 and list2 have the same length
for(int i = 0;i<list1.size();i++){
   list1.get(i); // do something with that
   list2.get(i); // do something else with that
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use normal for loop instead of foreach

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to change the data structures:

```
for (int i = 0; i < startPoints.size() && i < endPoints.size(); i++) {
    Point startPoint = startPoints.get(i);
    Point endPoint = endPoints.get(i);
    g.fillOval(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, 10, 10);
    g.drawLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend, instead of relying on iteration to successfully stay in synch, to use a single `Line` class that contains two points. For each start and end point construct your `Line` object and insert it into an arraylist.

To get them out just iterate as follows:

```
for (Line line : lines) { // <-- How do I do I do 2 at the same time?
     g.fillOval(line.getStartPoint().x, line.getStartPoint().y, 10, 10);
     g.drawLine(line.getStartPoint().x, line.getStartPoint().y, line.getEndPoint().x, line.getEndPoint.y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do both at the same time using the 'foreach' for loop you have.

If you are sure the Lists are both the same size then use the loop:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < startPoints.size(); i++) { // <-- How do I do I do 2 at the same time?
             Point startPoint = startPoints.get(i);
             Point endPoint = endPoints.get(i);
             g.fillOval(startPoint .x, startPoint.y, 10, 10);
             g.drawLine(startPoint .x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your data (startPoint and endPoint) are related - put them within another class (say MyVector) that will have startPoint and endPoint members (of type Point). Having such structure you iterate over list of MyVector objects.