# How to eliminate the trailing white space after an ArrayList?

Tags: java, unit-testing, arraylist, junit

I am trying to create a test that asserts that two ArrayLists are equal.  When running the test, I am getting an error that there is one difference between the expected and actual: there is a whitespace at the end of the arraylist.

The problem isn't caused by anything inside the arraylist, the problem is after the close of the arraylist. As far as I know, there is no trim function for this in java or a junit test which ignores whitespace.

```java
ArrayList<Quote> expected = new ArrayList<>();

        Quote q1 = new Quote("Test Test", "This is a quote.");
        Quote q2 = new Quote("Author Two", "Quote 2.");
        Quote q3 = new Quote("Unknown", "This quote does not have an author.");
        Quote q4 = new Quote("Author Three-three", "Quote 3.");

        expected.add(q1); expected.add(q2); expected.add(q3); expected.add(q4);
```

What this gives me is: java.util.ArrayList<[This is a quote. - Test Test, Quote 2. - Author Two, This quote does not have an author. - Unknown, Quote 3. - Author Three-three]>_

(I put a underscore where the whitespace is)

What I expect is: java.util.ArrayList<[This is a quote. - Test Test, Quote 2. - Author Two, This quote does not have an author. - Unknown, Quote 3. - Author Three-three]>

This does not include a whitespace.

I don't know why I am getting the whitespace nor do I know how to get rid of it.  Any help would be appreciated.

For more context, the entire tester file

````java
public class ImportQuotesTest {

    BufferedReader reader;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\homba\\Documents\\QuotesProject\\src\\ImportQuotesTest.txt");

        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    }

    @Test
    public void fillList() throws IOException {
        ArrayList<Quote> actual = ImportQuotes.fillList(reader);
        ArrayList<Quote> expected = new ArrayList<>();

        Quote q1 = new Quote("Test Test", "This is a quote.");
        Quote q2 = new Quote("Author Two", "Quote 2.");
        Quote q3 = new Quote("Unknown", "This quote does not have an author.");
        Quote q4 = new Quote("Author Three-three", "Quote 3.");

        expected.add(q1); expected.add(q2); expected.add(q3); expected.add(q4);

        Assert.assertEquals(expected,actual);
    }
}```
````

Comment: You haven't shown the code that actually prints or compares your list. What does that look like?

Comment: I am just comparing the two as objects using Assert.assertEquals() like so

```java
Assert.assertEquals(expected,actual);
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add all relevant code there. Java does not magically add whitespace, so there must be something in your test. Try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: ...and what's the content of the file? Your issue might be inside `ImportQuotes.fillList(reader)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah yeah, I stumbled into that once! First of all, if you're doing a unit test, just iterate through the whole list and assert each element or build a String yourself. I think I saw this in eclipse. It's running its own version of junit somehow and I think the tests pass when running from mvn test in command line.

To answer your question short:

1. You can use Hamcrest if you can: [Assert about a List in Junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236880/assert-about-a-list-in-junit)
2. Iterate:
   `for (int i = 0; i< list1.size; i++) { assertEquals(list1.get(i), list2.get(i)); }`
3. `StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
   StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(); 
   list1.forEach(sb1::append); 
   list2.forEach(sb1::append);
   assertEquals(sb1.toString(), sb2.toString()`

Prefered way is number 1 or 3.

Comment: Yeah you're right, this test passes from the command line and only fails when I'm using Intellij.  Glad that I'm not doing something wrong.  Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't accept this answer, it's a hack, nor you should compare arrays in such a way. If anything, try with `Assert.assertArrayEquals`.

Comment: @x80486 assertArrayEquals will not work because this is a List object not an array.  The original assertEquals should work.

Comment: `assertEquals` eventually just runs the `equals` of the object (in this case the `ArrayList`). That is something fundamentally different from comparing the two `toString()`s. I'm not sure how the `equals` of your `Quote` class is implemented, but if that is comparing correctly, then I bet that your quotes are indeed different (even though they appear equal). Does your test succeed if you loop over them and compare them separately?

Comment: When you iterate over both lists, it's better to use [the Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985266/how-to-iterate-through-two-arraylists-simultaneously). On an ArrayList calling `.get()` isn't too terrible, but on a LinkedList calling `.get()` like that is pretty inefficient.

Comment: To test your suggestion, I made a little test:
```java
for (int i = 1; i < expected.size(); i++){
            Assert.assertTrue(expected.get(i).equals(actual.get(i)));
            //Assert.assertEquals(expected.get(i), actual.get(i));
        }
```
The assertTrue passes but the assertEquals fails.  If junit is using the equals method I made with my quote class I don't know why it fails:
```public boolean equals(Quote q) {
        if (quote.equals(q.getQuote()) && author.equals(q.getAuthor()))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: @RishikHombal You can try to use the debugger by setting a breakpoint on the `Assert.assertEquals` and step into it and see what paths it takes. If `.equals()` returns true, then `assertEquals` should do the same. I'm kind of curious now why they would differ.

Comment: @Ivar I am not too good with the debugger so I am not sure how to find the paths